# Serving React app on the server ReactDOMServer.renderToString and StaticRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to render my react app from the server express but it is throwing me an error:

```
throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: /Users/f/Documents/GitHub/my-app/server/app.js: Unexpected token (34:6)
  32 |   const context = {};
  33 |   const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
> 34 |       <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
     |       ^
  35 |         <App />
  36 |       </StaticRouter>
  37 |   );
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (/Users/f/Documents/GitHub/my-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/f/Documents/GitHub/my-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/f/Documents/GitHub/my-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3750:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/f/Documents/GitHub/my-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3494:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/f/Documents/GitHub/my-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3474:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (/Users/f/Documents/GitHub/my-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3404:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/f/Documents/GitHub/my-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3381:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/f/Documents/GitHub/my-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3344:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprListItem (/Users/f/Documents/GitHub/my-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4312:16)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseCallExpressionArguments (/Users/f/Documents/GitHub/my-app/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3573:20)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

//server.js

```
// server/app.js
import path from 'path';
import express from 'express';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import React from 'react';
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { App } from '../src/App';
const app = express();

// Setup logger
app.use(morgan(
    ':remote-addr - :remote-user [:date[clf]] ":method :url HTTP/:http-version" :status :res[content-length] :response-time ms'));
// use ejs templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// Serve static assets
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

// Always return the main index.html, so react-router render the route in the client
// app.get('*', (req, res) => {
//   console.log('hi from app.get');
//
//   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'));
// });



// universal routing and rendering
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const context = {};
  const markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
        <App />
      </StaticRouter>
  );

  // context.url will contain the URL to redirect to if a <Redirect> was used
  if (context.url) {
    return res.redirect(302, context.url);
  }

  // TODO manage 404
  const status = context.matchedRoutes.page.is404 ? 404 : 200;
  return res.status(status).render('index', { markup });
});



module.exports = app;
```

and my app

```
export const App = () => (
    <div className="App">
      <Helmet title="You Are Doing Great" />
      <Header />
      <Routes />
      <Footer />
    </div>
);
export default App;
```

and my routes like this

```
const Switches = props => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/projects" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/projects/:ProjectId" component={SingleProject} />
    <Route component={NotFound} contextData={{ is404: true }} />
  </Switch>
);
```

what i am trying to do is to render the react app from my server. I get an error in webstorm that renderToString is a unresolved function or method.

I don't understand what i am missing here.
i used [this Github](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4789) reference.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific error, you have to enable JSX for your server app as well.

The `unexpected token` error is because the parser didn't recognize the `<` character since it's part of JSX and not JavaScript itself.